# ExtJS is not using my grid filter override

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have a project in which I needed to make a custom grid date filter.

Everything work fine until the stateful save. I need to add a custom value to the state. I overrode the `getState` method from a class that extends `Ext.util.Filter` :

```
Ext.define('RelativeDateUtilFilter', {
extend: 'Ext.util.Filter',


getState: function () {
    var config = this.getInitialConfig(),
        result = {},
        name;


    for (name in config) {
        if (config.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            result[name] = config[name];
        }
    }


    delete result.root;
    result.value = this.getValue();

    //this is the line I added
    result.relValue = this.relValue;


    this.callParent();


    return result;
}
});
```

I have an override of the filter base class to make it use my own util filter :

```
createFilter: function (config, key) {
        var filter = new RelativeDateUtilFilter(this.getFilterConfig(config, key));
        filter.isGridFilter = true;
        return filter;
    }
```

The problem is, my `getState` in the `RelativeDateUtilFilter` class is only called when I created the filter for the first time. When ExtJS saves the state it uses the one in the base class `Ext.util.Filter`.
I can sort of workaround by putting my code directly in the `Ext.util.Filter` class, but I don't want to since it is not good in case I want to upgrade for example.

In short, how to force ExtJS to use my own `getState` method when writing the state ?

Any help is appreciated !

## EDIT :

In case this ever helps someone, I fixed this by removing my `RelativeDateUtilFilter` class and my filter base override, and putting my `getState` method in an override file :

```
Ext.define('Override.util.Filter', {
    override :'Ext.util.Filter',

    getState: function () {
        var config = this.getInitialConfig(),
            result = {},
            name;

        for (name in config) {
            // We only want the instance properties in this case, not inherited ones,
            // so we need hasOwnProperty to filter out our class values.
            if (config.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                result[name] = config[name];
            }
        }

        delete result.root;
        result.value = this.getValue();

        if(this.relValue) {
            result.relValue = this.relValue;
        }

        return result;
    }
});
```

(in a /overrides/util/Filter,js file, so it is loaded correctly by SenchaCMD)

## Thanks again @bullettrain !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in your case you dont need this.callParent(); part in your overriden method, here is a nice explanation about different ways to override a method https://sencha.guru/2015/01/20/overriding-methods-safely/